# Script running once in month but not using cron job

Tags: algorithm, cron

I am unable to run cron job for my project, it runs on localhost. I need to run a process once in a month. Here I am thinking of login as trigger.

```
if (date is 01/MM/YYYY and user is superadmin) 

run this script
```

My problem is, if the **superadmin logs in more than once then script will run again**. what should be my code to prevent that. I can simply put a button for renew, bt not considering that for an option.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file and call it: `last_run.txt` and in this file you'll update the current date every time your script finishes to run.

Whenever the superadmin logs in, before running your script, check this file and see if the date is the current date - if it is: bail out, if it's not - run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a similar approach as daemons do. Daemons usually use a pid-file which is located under /var/run to ensure a single instance of the daemon. Why don't create a run-file where you remember the last month you run the script. On every login you check if for this month the script has already been executed?
Why can't you use cron?